# ASP.NET Core Razor Pages Routing With parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a simple page where users can search for records based on start and end date, and the Reference and Client fields are optional

on the details page I have this

```
@page "{datestart}/{dateend}/{referenceId?}/{client?}"
```

on the search page I have this post handler

```
    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var options = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions() { AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10) };
            ViewData["ReferenceId"] = new SelectList(_context.Referencias.AsNoTracking().FromCache(), "Id", "Name");

            return Page();
        }

        return RedirectToPage("Details", new
        {
            datestart= SearchViewModel.DateStart.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),
            dateend = SearchViewModel.DateEnd.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),
            referenceId = SearchViewModel.ReferenceId,
            client = SearchViewModel.Client
        });
    }
```

However everything works well except when the Reference field is null

on my details page

```
  public void OnGet(string datestart, string dateend, int? referenceId, int? client)
```

The intended result was that i would be able to go to details page if i don't supply a referenceId event if i did supply a client.

The dates are always required though.

So is there a way that i can still route even if referenceId is not supplied but client is?

All i get is this exception

> InvalidOperationException: No page named 'Details' matches the
>   supplied values.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.RedirectToPageResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext
>   context, RedirectToPageResult result)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RedirectToPageResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult
>   result)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsync()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref
>   bool isCompleted)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext
>   context) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref
>   State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   httpContext)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   httpContext)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)
>   NToastNotify.NtoastNotifyAjaxToastsMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext
>   context, RequestDelegate next)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass5_1+<b__1>d.MoveNext()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)

Also I tried switch the order of {referenceId?} and {client?} and it worked but then it fails if i do the same for referenceId.

**UPDATE**

As per @Nick suggestion I tried once again with multiple routes and it except for the 2nd route, it won't route if it's the only one.

```
options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Production","/BackOffice/Account/Records/Details", "{datestart}/{dateend}/{client?}");
             options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Production", "/BackOffice/Account/Records/Details", "{datestart}/{dateend}/{referenceId?}");
             options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Production", "/BackOffice/Account/Records/Details", "{datestart}/{dateend}/{client?}/{referenceId?}");
```

Comment: i don't think so, you might need to introduce overloads

Comment: How could i achieve this?

Comment: you can create a pagemodel with those 4 parameters as properties see below : https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing

Comment: Probably the best solution is to use query string values instead of route parameters. Otherwise you won't be able to disambiguate between the `referenceid` and `clientid` when one is missing.

Comment: Or you can make `referenceid` required and pass in `0` when there isn't one...

Comment: thanks that's exactly what i did @MikeBrind

Comment: If your app permits  `clientid` or a `referenceid`, the accepted answer will not work for the reasons I provided in the comments I posted to it. Use one of my previous suggestions, or provide a bit more detail on the parameters that the page expects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to be able to cater for either a `referenceid` or a `clientid`, or both, you can either make the first parameter required and pass in 0, or you can use a query string. Otherwise there is no way for routing to know if the `42` on the end of `/details/2019-8-15/2019-8-16/42` is a `clientid` or a `referenceid` value.

As you have discovered, as far as routing is concerned

```
"{datestart}/{dateend}/{client?}"
```

is the same as

```
"{datestart}/{dateend}/{referenceid?}"
```

and will generate an `AmbiguousActionException`.

If you want to make the first parameter required, the way to do that is as follows:

```
@page "{datestart}/{dateend}/{referenceid:int=0}/{client?}"
```

Any  link internally generated by the tag helper will automatically populate the `referenceid` segment with `0` unless another value is supplied.

Answer (score 1):

Might be an odd way but you can add an addtional root by using the AddPageRoute method.

```cs
    services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
       options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/details", "{datestart}/{dateend}/{client?}");
    });
```

Comment: This will match a route where the optional `referenceid` is provided but the optional `clientid` is not.

Comment: If you keep the current root in the razor page this should work fine.

Comment: how do you specify an area in this route?

Comment: You could try to use the AddAreaPageRoute method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.pageconventioncollectionextensions.addareapageroute?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: this does seem to work, the only difference is that the referenceId appears as a query string format after client "client?referenceId=10", I tried even set multiple routes with each parameter but gave me an error of too many endpoints

Comment: Did you kept the routing value in your razor page and added one using the AddPageRoute method addtionally? Because that worked fine for me.

Comment: If a `referenceid` is provided, but no `clientid` is provided, your additional route will be matched, but the `referencid` will be bound to the `clientid` parameter.

Comment: i udpated my post with what i implemented, it works except for 2nd route just for a referenceId